# How to require or evaluate gzipped JavaScript file with Node.js and zlib?

Tags: node.js, gzip, require, zlib

> Everything works when I require a normal JavaScript file in Node:

```
var test = require('test.js');
console.log(test.foo); // prints the function
```

But now I have compressed that `test.js` file, reading it as a `string` works:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();

var buffer = [];
fs.createReadStream('test.js.gz').pipe(gunzip);
gunzip.on('data', function(data){
  buffer.push(data.toString())
});
gunzip.on('finish', function(){
  console.log(buffer.join("")); //prints the JS file as string    
}).on("error", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

But, I don't want a `string`. Using `eval` does not seem right.

How can I evaluate the `string` as a JavaScript similar to what I get with require('test.js'); (I cannot use external libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation:

```
const Module = require('module');
const zlib   = require('zlib');
const fs     = require('fs');

function requireGZ(filename) {
  let code = zlib.gunzipSync(fs.readFileSync(filename)).toString();
  let mod  = new Module();

  mod._compile(code, filename);

  return mod.exports;
}

// Use:
let test = requireGZ('./test.js.gz');
```

Comment: Thank you but I cannot use external libraries for this.

Comment: @iwek I've edited my answer to provide a possible implementation that doesn't rely on external libraries.

Comment: Thank you! fyi, I had to drop "use strict"; on top as node threw SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: @iwek ah yeah I tested with Node v6 :)